# Ffmpeg convert images to video error in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

My main goal is creating a video file using series of images. then I build the Ffmpeg library to android using [Roman10 Tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/).

When creating a android app I add .so files and ffmpeg File to assert folder.

Then executing command,

> ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg a.mov

Then following error display in my LogCat,

> 04-20 09:47:16.133: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103***
>   04-20 09:47:16.133: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102***
>   04-20 09:47:16.133: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100***
>   04-20 09:47:16.133: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100***
>   04-20 09:47:16.133: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100***
>   04-20 09:47:16.133: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095):  * libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101***
>   04-20 09:47:16.143: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095):  * [mjpeg @ 0x1fffc0] bits 222 is invalid***
>   04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095):  * Last message repeated 25 times***
>   04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095):  * [image2 @ 0x1ff180] decoding for stream 0 failed***
>   04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): * [image2 @ 0x1ff180] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown)): unspecified size***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *nConsider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): */storage/emulated/0/com.example.createvideo/frame_%05d.jpg: could not find codec parameters***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *Input #0, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/com.example.createvideo/frame_%05d.jpg':***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *  Duration: 00:00:01.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *[buffer @ 0x1ff020] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *[buffer @ 0x1ff020] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *[buffer @ 0x1ff020] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *[buffer @ 0x1ff020] Error setting option video_size to value 0x0.***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x1ff100] Error applying options to the filter.***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *Error opening filters!***
>
> 04-20 09:47:16.163: V/MJPEG_FFMPEG(1095): *Ending FFMPEG***

I set the -analyzeduration and -probesize but same LogCat displayed.

Please someone help me to do this.

Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't encode your image for the container where you want to put them on. For mov file, you can encode your images with qtrle.

So try this command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -f image2 -i img%1d.png -r 25 -vcodec qtrle output.mov
```

Comment: Thanx for answer.. @Sandra ,  I try it but same error displayed. I change the command in many ways but error log is same.

Comment: Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size***, Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format***, Error setting option video_size to value 0x0.***; The command you give doesn't reflect those attributes

Comment: ya, finally video created. I set image scale to `-s 640x480` and pixel format to `-pix_fmt  yuv420p`. thanx for helping me.